# Visual Studio tells me that an operational local IIS URL has not been configured

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, iis-7.5

I am trying to get a web application project working, after we moved from a StarTeam repository to a TFS repository.  I have a web site on my local IIS for the project; this web site is up and serving static content when I test it, but when I copy and past the URL to that site into the Local IIS Web server's Project Url in VS 2010, I get a message that the local IIS URL has not been configured.  The popup that displays this message offers me the chance to create a new virtual directory, but this fails.  Anyway, this is not what I wish to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually find myself setting things up in IIS and then copying the URL into VS, but I ensure:

1. IIS has IIS6 management compatibility components installed.
2. The folder in IIS is the root of a web application.
3. The app pool for the web app is configured with the correct .NET version.

Comment: Thanks Richard, but your answer reads like a checklist of everything I've already done :-(  Good points though.

Comment: This checklist didn't fix it for me either. I don't understand why this is marked as the answer when it is not.

Answer (score 0):

And to add to Richard's answer:

4. Ensure the site's binding in IIS is set to "All Unassigned"